# Simpleaudio wav file only plays once

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Apologies in advance as I am new to coding. I am writing a simple program using python on a rasbperry pi. It is supposed to  play a random file from a list of wav files contained in a folder each time a motion is detected.  I originally had the "play random file code" and the "motion detector code" in two separately files and they each worked fine.  However, when combining them, a wav file is only played the first time a motion is detected (however, each time a motion is detected it DOES print "Playing Sound".  Tkinter is there as I have future plans to add a record button to add new sounds via a little touchscreen I have as well. I'm certain it's something simple and until I can find out what I'm doing wrong I am continuing to watch python tutorials.  Code is below

```
from tkinter import *
import glob
import random
import time
import simpleaudio as sa
from gpiozero import LED
from gpiozero import MotionSensor

green_led = LED(17)
pir = MotionSensor(4)
sound_list = glob.glob("sounds/*.wav")
sound_item = random.choice(sound_list)
wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(sound_item)
play_obj = wave_obj.play()

green_led.off()

while True:

    pir.wait_for_motion()
    print("Motion Detected")
    green_led.on()

    play_obj.wait_done() #Wait until sound has finished playing
    print("Playing Sound")

    pir.wait_for_no_motion()
    green_led.off()
    print("No Motion")
```

Comment: you could alternatively use `pygame` module to play audio. give it a try?

Comment: thanks cloud I did consider trying a different import.  I'll give it a shot here in a bit

Comment: ill jus provide a easy way, just try saying `pygame.mixer.init()` to initialise and then later say `pygame.mixer.music.load(file_name)` and then `pygame.mixer.music.play()` to play the music and it supports wav and mp3 and if it does not support wav try converting it?

Comment: I got it close but now it only picks one random sound upon running the module and only plays that same random song while the program is running each time a motion is detected.  I need it (while the program is running) to select a different random sound each time a motion is detected. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: figured it out.  Pygame works a lot better than simpleaudio.  Code was bloated I combined your tip with this article: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=187824